# training kl-divergence loss is higher than testing kl loss, any reason for that?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, neural-networks, autoencoders

[image]

I have plotted the training and testing KL loss for my model but it seems that testing loss is always lower than training loss? Shouldn't it be higher than training loss? Or does it mean the model is messed up?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the network trained to minimize total loss, i.e. reconstruction loss plus KL loss? I'm guessing that even if test KL loss is lower than train KL loss, the total loss on the test set is greater than the total training loss. So, whatever you've gained by a lower KL loss is given back in terms of worse reconstruction. Alternatively, the model could be underfitting.

Comment: yes, you are right, the training total loss is lower than the testing total loss. So why in this case is it underfitting?

Comment: Without any distinguishing information, it seems like the usual explanations apply.